# Zoom in on JLabel icon with netbeans GUI builder JSlider

Tags: java, swing, zooming, jlabel, jslider

I have a JPanel which in turn has a JLabel with an icon. I'm using this JLabel as a background image. I want to be able to zoom in this image with the help of JSlider while using the netbeans GUI Builder but I can't seem to workout the stateChangedListener. Any help would be appreciated.
 Here's what I've got so far:
1- This is how I set the Image

```
public static void setImage(JLabel label,String path) {
    ImageIcon myImage=new ImageIcon(path);
    Image img=myImage.getImage();
    Image newImg=img.getScaledInstance(label.getWidth(), label.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    ImageIcon image=new ImageIcon(newImg);
    label.setIcon(image);
}
```

This is my stateChangedListener, it scales the image with +10 to the JLabel's height and width but the problem is that it will have to add a new image each time the slider is adjusted.

```
private void jSlider1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                      
    int value = jSlider1.getValue(); 

    if(value==55){
        String path=System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+"sources"+File.separator+"1891.jpg";
        ImageIcon myImage=new ImageIcon(path);
        Image img=myImage.getImage();
        Image newImg=img.getScaledInstance(label.getWidth()+10, label.getHeight()+10,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon image=new ImageIcon(newImg);
        label.setIcon(image);    

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the image from the label's icon and then enlarge it:

```
private void jSlider1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                      
    int value = jSlider1.getValue(); 

    if(value==55) {
        ImageIcon myImage = (ImageIcon) label.getIcon();
        Image img = myImage.getImage();
        Image newImg = img.getScaledInstance(label.getWidth()+10, label.getHeight()+10,Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        label.setIcon( new ImageIcon(newImg) );
    }
}
```

This way you'll avoid creating a new image from the image file, however you'll still have to obtain a new image scaled instance with `getScaledInstance`.

Hope this helps